# Problema con consultas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cuento con una base de datos de estudiantes de una universidad en la que cada planilla corresponde a una materia en particular. 
El DER(Diagrama Entidad Relación) es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo problemas con los siguientes enunciados a resolver:

**1) Mostrar el alumno con nota más alta en cada instancia evaluativa**

```
select Tipo.Nombre [Instancia], MAX(Evaluacion.Nota) [Nota más alta]
from Evaluacion
inner join Tipo on Tipo.IDTipo = Evaluacion.IDTipo
group by Tipo.Nombre
order by Tipo.Nombre
```

Con esta consulta muestro la nota más alta de cada instancia evaluativa, pero no sé de que manera mostrar el nombre del estudiante.

**2) Mostrar el promedio de desaprobados en cada instancia.**

Se que en ambas se debe utilizar `subconsulta` pero no se de que manera implementarla ya que todavía no trabajamos con la misma. De ante mano gracias por su ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Tipo.Nombre [Instancia], MAX(Evaluacion.Nota) [Nota más alta],
Estudiante.Nombre [Nombre del estudiante]
FROM Evaluacion
INNER JOIN Estudiante on Estudiante.IDEstudiante = Evaluacion.IDEstudiante
INNER JOIN Tipo on Tipo.IDTipo = Evaluacion.IDTipo
group by Tipo.Nombre, Estudiante.Nombre
order by Tipo.Nombre
```

Comment: Hola @Nex Saloj da como resultado lo mismo a lo que planteó francisco..

Comment: @AguFortini Creo que ahora si comprendo, lo que quieres obtener es la Instancia, la nota y el estudiante:
Matemática, José, 100
Literatura, Juan, 100

Prueba si ésto funciona o similar:
SELECT Tipo.Nombre , MAX(Evaluacion.Nota) ,
Estudiante.Nombre 
FROM Evaluacion
INNER JOIN Estudiante on Estudiante.IDEstudiante = Evaluacion.IDEstudiante
INNER JOIN Tipo on Tipo.IDTipo = Evaluacion.IDTipo
group by Tipo.Nombre, Estudiante.Nombre
**HAVING** MAX(Evaluacion.Nota) = (SELECT MAX(Evaluacion.Nota FROM Evaluacion WHERE Tipo.IDTipo = Evaluacion.IDTipo LIMIT 1)
order by Tipo.Nombre

Answer (score 1):

```
Select es.* , ev.* From Evaluación as ev
Inner join estudiante as es on ev.idestudiante = es.idestudiante;
```

Con esto traes todos los datos de las evaluaciones y todos los datos de los estudiantes.

En tu consulta deberías agregar la tabla estudiante

```
select es.nombre, es.apellido ,Tipo.Nombre [Instancia], MAX(Evaluacion.Nota) [Nota más alta] from Evaluacion inner join Tipo on Tipo.IDTipo = Evaluacion.IDTipo
Inner join estudiantes AS es ON evaluación.idestudiante=es.idestudiante 
 group by Tipo.Nombre order by Tipo.Nombre
```

Con esto debería traer los nombres de los estudiantes. Inténtalo y avisa.

Comment: Hola @francisco castillo , probé pero me trae todas las notas, y sólo necesito los nombres de los estudiantes con las más altas.